# Linking APK for automatic install on my website

Tags: android, hyperlink, installation

It looks like I cant use WordPress to host my .apk because the site doesn't allow this for security reasons.  Anyone else have this problem?

Does the Android OS automatically start the install activity when the apk is downloaded?  I know that amazon store automatically takes you to the install activity but how do i make this happen with a direct link to the apk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to provide a download link for your *.apk file, and Android will recognize it as an Android app, and initiate the install when appropriate.

If you want to support a link to your app in the Play Market, you can supply this URL: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.id`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any sites that allow .apk attachments? WP doesn't seem to allow it

Comment: You could provide a link to a Public Dropbox or something.  I know you can download APK files from there.  Don't forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: unless for some odd reason you don't want your .apk on the play store, the best option is usually through the play store. A totally seamless and without user interaction option will not exist. I would also suggestion you on the website to suggest the download and do not force it to download as most users (including myself) consider it a bad behaviour and won't trust to install something pushed to me.

Comment: The file extension may be insufficient. You may also need to configure the server to serve up `.apk` files as having the `application/vnd.android.package-archive` MIME type.